# What is the data/data/package.name/lib folder for

Tags: android

Unlike other app-folders like *cache, shared_prefs* and *databases*, that are only created when first needed, *lib* is always present but so far always empty. What is this folder for?

Comment: IIRC, that will hold `.so` files from the NDK, should you start using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lib/` directory for a project in `/data/data/your.package.here/` will hold the architecture-specific `.so` files for any NDK-supplied libraries. By "architecture-specific", I mean that if you are running an ARM CPU, it will hold an ARM `.so`; if you are running an x86 CPU, it will hold an x86 `.so`, etc.

It is possible there is something else that will go in `lib/`. There's a slight itch at the back of my brain suggesting there is, but I cannot remember what, and the itch might just be a bug bite. :-)

Comment: can you tell where i have to put the .so files on eclipse project, to make they be "extracted" to the /data/data/your.package.here/lib folder ? I have already compile the libs for arm arch